# How would I run this on a chromebook?

Tags: linux, batch-file, file-transfer, gaming, file-conversion

I have made a [text adventure game](https://confusingfool93.itch.io/hellish-daybreak) for windows but would like to expand to other operating systems. I have people on discord helping me with converting it to Macintosh OS, but I would like to have it available on Linux aswell. If you would like to try out I posted a prototype version for Windows. If it helps you can also just have the [source code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MCfGH0vkSl8ZITF0Z07nj8y94eMT_yju/view?usp=sharing). NOTE: The game was made in Notepad, and saved as a .bat file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also would like to know how to run it on Chromebook..

Comment: If you simply made it a bash shell script to run on macOS, you use the same bash script on the Chromebook. To access the shell on a Chromebook, you might have to put it in developer mode. [Enabling developer mode](https://www.androidcentral.com/how-enable-developer-mode-chrome-os)

Comment: @DrZoo Looking at the script I don't think that's necessary. If bash cannot be accessed from crosh without administrative rights then an app should be used instead which interprets the shell commands.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities to learn how to use your program on another platform.

For the moment, as far as I can see, you mostly use goto and echo statements. It should be possible to install [Dosbox](https://www.dosbox.com/) in one way or another (app store, chrome web store, google play) and run your script in Dosbox on every platform where Dosbox can be run. Your next steps would be to break up your script into functions instead of using goto statements. You could learn about [bash](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) and port your code to bash which now runs on Linux, Mac OS and Windows (Cygwin, MinGW, WSL…) or you could try to make it a simple interactive website/slideshow with modern HTML, JavaScript and CSS. If you want to learn more about programming you will have to learn all of this eventually. Just don't get caught up in micromanagement. There is nothing wrong about installing Dosbox on a Chrombook/Mac or Bash on Windows. :-)

Edit: On second thought you should get a book on how to start programming. Pick any topic you like then get a book and read it. If you want to learn developing websites, get a book about HTML with Javascript and CSS. Android Apps -> Java or Kotlin. iOS Apps -> Swift(?). Linux Scripting -> Python and Bash. Windows Scripting -> Powershell. The ideal book should teach you: How to setup and use your first IDE (can be Android Studio or VI, you decide). Give you an overview of the language an what you can achieve with it so you can decide what you want to pursue further. There are way more efficient tools than Notepad and you should learn about them sooner than later. :-)

Comment: well... I tried running it on DosBOX, but it just crashed. And I converted my coding to .sh (bash) and it wouldn't run on MAC?/!?!?! PS: This is the same person who posted this question, I just don't have an account...

Comment: Debugging your code is part of learning a language. You need patience and time to research why your code does not what you want. Get a book, I recommend Python if you are interested in portable and capable scripting, read it. Install tools like pylint and read a styleguide. You can save yourself from a lot of frustration this way and get a few things done that motivate you to approach things you can't solve today at another time.